# How do I return eval(code) and get an object back with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, eval

I have this bit of code. What I want it to do is is load a .js file and then run it. wWen it runs I want it to return a parameter or even better an object.

This is the code in my page

```
var runCode = function(){
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET','io.js',false);
    xhr.send();
    return eval(xhr.responseText);
};
```

And this is the is.js

```
var IO = new function(){
    this.run = true;
    return 'io';
};
return IO
```

But when I run it i get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement" in the console.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution I found is to encapsulate your string to be `eval`'d inside a function, which is quite simple.

```
return eval("(function() {" + xhr.responseText + "})();");
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use return outside of a function. But to return a value from eval you can use the following syntax-

```
eval('var IO = function(){this.run = true; return "io";};{IO};')
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use `IO;` as the final statement? Braces aren't that necessary.

Comment: yeah, using just IO works too. I was trying to write it as an object to make eval return it

Comment: That `{IO}` at the end is what did. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, you can't return outside of a function. What you'll need to is to `return IO;` from your `runCode` function after the request completes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `new` statement

```
var IO = function(){ 
    this.run = true; 
    return 'io'; 
}; 
return IO
```