# Javascript object literal syntax with just field name, no value

Tags: javascript, syntax

While debugging some code, I came across something which looked like it shouldn't work. If I create a basic example in the Chrome console, it works too.

```
var id = 1;
var o = { id };
o;
```

This creates and prints the following object:

{ id: 1 }

Example:

[image]

What's going on here? The only question I can find with a similar syntax is this one:

[JavaScript object literal syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912497/javascript-object-literal-syntax)

...and the answers to that say it is just a code block, which clearly here it is not.

Comment: It's a new-ish syntax that won't work in old browsers.

Comment: that's always a problem without knowing the right term for searching ...